# Как можно исправить эту ошибку?

Tags: c

[image]

> error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Comment: м.б. инициализировать переменные?

Comment: те что в условии? я их в самом начале инициализировал же,или ещё раз нужно?

Comment: начальные значение задайте им)

Comment: а то, что есть в начале кода - это объявление переменной, а  не инициализация)

Comment: Там же scanf есть

Answer (score 1):

во первых что вам мешает скопировать код из проекта сюда? или при любой непонятной ситуации сразу хватаетесь за телефон?

во вторых `=` - это присваивание, `==` - это сравнение

```
if (num < 0 || base < 0 || base == 0)
```

да и эта проверка избыточная - замените на

```
if (num < 0 || base <= 0)
```

в третьих проверка с `minus` у вас вообще всегда не срабатывает потому что вы переменную `minus` нигде не меняете до ее сравнения и он всегда равен 0

Comment: не угадали) скрин с экрана ноутбука. По поводу minus, получается условие всегда не срабатывает?

Comment: да, у вам `minus = 0`, вы его нигде не меняете, поэтому `if (0)` никогда не срабатывает

Answer (score 0):

```
if (... || base=0)
```

Тут вы не сравниваете, а присваиваете 0 в base.

Поменяйте на

```
if (... || base == 0)
```